# is the ruby mysqlplus adapter production ready

Tags: mysql, ruby, rubygems, adapter

is the ruby mysqlplus adapter production ready?

have a choice between:
 1. mysql library by tmtm (has a pure ruby and c version)
 2. mysqlplus by http://github.com/oldmoe/mysqlplus/
 3. dataobjects (used my datamapper ORM)
 4. em-mysql

Currently using the C version of the mysql gem, that is the oldest and most popular option.
Evented programming is hard, invasive and is a paradigm-shift so that rules out em-mysql :-)

How mature are dataobjects and mysqlplus, was more interested in mysqlplus due to its concurrent driver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am the maintainer of DataMapper, and we've been using DataObjects under the hood for several years.

It is production ready. In many ways it is further along than most of other ruby drivers. It supports MRI, JRuby and even Rubinius. It had full Ruby 1.9 coding support very early on. It works with Ruby 1.8.6 to 1.9.2. It has non-blocking support. It handles typecasting of values without any intermediary steps (so the data doesn't come out as a String to be coerced into another ruby type; it comes back as the type directly). It has a unified API between all the DB drivers it supports (currently sqlite, mysql, postgresql, oracle, sqlserver, h2, hsql and derby).

Actually there's a rubysoc project to port AR/ARel to work with DO, and there's a chance it could become the default driver for ActiveRecord.

Comment: datamapper/DataObjects is good and has a nice community :-) 
Hoping DataObjects becomes the standard.

Comment: accepting DO as there is no other response. It is a good library.